# Error 'open' called on an object that does not implement interface XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I get this error when I'm trying to launch an ajax request inside of a class from another class function.
You can get the error in firefox console from this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/d2o1d0eu/

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGwwKG

```
var MyClass = new Class({

    initialize: function(options){

        this.my_request = new Request({
            url: '/echo/html/',
            method: 'post',
            onSuccess: function(resp) {
                alert(resp);
            }
        });

    },

    request: function(param){

        this.my_request.send('html='+param);

    }   

});

var MySecondClass = new Class({

    Implements: [Options],

    options: {
        first_class: {}
    },

    initialize: function(options){

        this.setOptions(options);

        this.options.first_class.request('internal'); // error

    },

    request: function(param){

        this.options.first_class.request(param);

    }

});

var unknown_name = new MyClass();
// unknown_name.request('unknown_name test'); // ok

var test = new MySecondClass({

    'first_class': unknown_name

});

// test.request('second class test'); // error
```

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, the `Options` mixin uses [`Object.merge`](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Types/Object#Object:Object-merge), which does a recursive copy of the passed `options` argument.

In your code, you're passing an instance of `MyClass` as an option to an instance of `MySecondClass`. When you pass an object this way, `Object.merge` will recursively clone the object. That means that in your second class, `this.options.first_class.my_request` is actually a *clone* of a `Request` instance, with all of the instance's object properties being cloned as well.

This presents a problem, since the actual `XMLHttpRequest` object of the `Request` class is cloned in the process. What you get in the end is a base object (i.e, it only inherits from `Object.prototype`) that has all the properties and methods of an actual `XMLHttpRequest` instance but is **not** an actual instance. Since the methods of `XMLHttpRequest` think that you're trying to call the methods on non-instances, you get a DOMException.

The take-away is this: *do not pass `Class` instances as options*. Instead, pass them as separate parameters: `new MySecondClass(unknown_name, options)`.