Get full list of keys that CSSStyleDeclaration understands
I want a list of all the CSS property names the browser understands.
Using an arbitrary CSSStyleDeclaration object as follows does a pretty good job:
const styles = getComputedStyle(document.body);
const styleNames = Array.from(Array(styles.length), (_, i) => styles[i])
styleNames // Array(370) [ "accent-color", "align-content", "align-items", "align-self", 
// "animation-composition", "animation-delay", "animation-direction", "animation-duration", 
// "animation-fill-mode", "animation-iteration-count", … ]

However, this doesn't include any shorthand styles. Even though the CSSStyleDeclaration object can understand shorthand properties when it's queried for them (e.g. styles["margin"]), I have been unable to find a way to retrieve these keys. How can I do this?

Interestingly, the solution is completely different for Firefox and Chrome (the only two I tested).
For Firefox:
const styles = getComputedStyle(document.body);
// Get the keys of the prototype
const allKeys = Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(styles));
// The above list includes both the caterpillar-case and camelCase variants of property names
const styleNames = allKeys.filter((key) => key.toLowerCase() === key);
styleNames // Array(546) [ "align-content", "-webkit-align-content", "align-items", 
// "-webkit-align-items", "align-self", "-webkit-align-self", "aspect-ratio", 
// "backface-visibility", "-webkit-backface-visibility", "baseline-source", … ]

For Chrome:
const styles = getComputedStyle(document.body);
// Slice out the keys that are just index values
const styleNames = Object.keys(styles).slice(styles.length).map((name) => {
    // Convert camelCase into caterpillar-case and fix the -webkit- prefix
    return name.replace(/[A-Z]/g, (letter) => "-" + letter.toLowerCase())
               .replace("webkit", "-webkit");
});
styleNames // Array(631) [ "accent-color", "additive-symbols", "align-
// content", "align-items", "align-self", "alignment-baseline", "all", 
// "anchor-name", "animation", "animation-composition", … ]

To verbalise the difference, in FireFox all possible keys the object will recognize are explicitly defined on the prototype. In Chrome, there are no keys on the prototype (rather some methods) and instead listing the keys on the object itself will first list the indices for the "longhand-only list" (like Firefox does), but then after that starts the full list of CSS properties, camelCase only.
Additional Notes.
In Firefox, you have to be very particular in calling Object.keys on the prototype, as anything that asks to generate the values of those keys (e.g. Object.entries) will fail with the error
Uncaught TypeError: 'get alignContent' called on an object that does not implement interface CSS2Properties.


Thank you for explaining this error .. a bit.  This here was one of only 3(!) hits on this error in Google.  So this error definitively needs a lot more documentation, because I am completely left in the dark what this error wants to tell me and what to do to properly circumvent it.  (Read: Why did FF chose to break JavaScript by throwing an error instead of just returning undefined as usual?  If there is some clue behind it, I am apparently too dumb to find it myself.)

@Tino I'm happy to have helped! Firefox definitely has an interesting implementation, to say the least... It's already strange enough that it's interfacing CSS2Properties and not CSSStyleDeclaration, when clearly it's handling more than CSS2 styles... I couldn't find anything in the W3C for the prototype of this object. It seems this kind of "object does not implement interface" error is FF specific, and happens when e.g. some DOM object is deep cloned to include all the methods and one of these methods is called on the non-instance...? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35366980/11493659
